# How to calculate the cardano's network throughput (transactions per second)?

Tags: transactions, cryptocurrency, cardano

I've been searching about the Cardano's network throughput in TPS (transactions per second) and read in [this](https://www.blockchain-council.org/cryptocurrency/top-cryptocurrencies-with-their-high-transaction-speeds/#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20key%20features%20of%20Cardano%20is%20its%20transaction,speed%20Blockchain%20platforms%20like%20EOS.) website that is about 1000, in [this other one](https://blocktrade.com/learn/cardano-vs-solana/#:%7E:text=Although%20it%20typically%20averages%20approximately,with%20270%20transactions%20per%20second.) that it is 270.

But when I try to actually calculate it using the [average transaction size](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/216/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-transactions-a-block-can-hold/292#292) (613 Bytes) and the [maximum block size](https://cexplorer.io/params) (90112 Bytes) I get that a block can hold about 147 transactions, knowing that the activeSlotCoefficient is 0.05 (therefore the block time is 20 seconds). I can conclude that the throughput is:

147tx / 20s = 7.35 TPS. Which seems like I'm doing something wrong.

How do I actually calculate the throughput, and what am I doing wrong?